# Get element by repeater with specific value in Protractor?

Tags: angularjs, protractor

Can I filter `by.repeater('object in array')` so it returns just objects with a specific value in Protractor?

E.g. something like

```
var filteredElements = element.all(by.repeater('object in array')).column('object.type').value('car'));
```

Is something like this possible without creating additional loops (and without creating new promises)?

Comment: What did you end up doing?

Comment: I've explained it in detail in this issue on Protractors Github account: https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/877. Please also post a comment there, if you want this feature, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These elements doesn't have any unique identifier? If they have you can do a cssSelector searching for that specific identifier (id, class or any other attributes..)

If they don't have ny unique identifier, the best way to do that is change you FE application to add the class "car" to each element that you want to have, and then, have a selector that retrieves all the element with class "car".

Comment: I'll mark your answer as accepted as this is one way to do it, but this was more an API problem which is now solved as seen in the link from my comment under my question. See https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/877